# What does it mean to be an "instance of a rewriting rule"?

Tags: computer-science, definition, formal-languages

What is the definition of the following statement?

> The rewriting rule $l_{1}\rightarrow r_{1}$ is an instance of another rule $l_{2}\rightarrow r_{2}$.

PS:This statement comes from the paper of term rewriting systems which is called "only prime superpositions need be considered in the Knuth-Bendix completion procedure".

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you mean (but that might just be me). Can you perhaps give some more context?

Comment: (Can you give an example of what you mean? I wonder if you mean something like $a^3\rightarrow a$ is an instance of $a^2\rightarrow a$?)

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed! The fact that noone who knows the definition has come across this question yet is not reason to close it!

Comment: Presumably, this question comes from the context of term rewriting systems. In that case, the answer is a straightforward recapitulation of the definition - $l_1 \to r_1$ is an instance of $l_2 \to r_2$ if there is a substitution $\sigma$ such that $l_1 = \sigma(l_2)$ and $r_1 = \sigma(r_2)$. Nevertheless, unless the context is made clear, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the comments, an instance $\ell_1 \to r_1$ of a rewrite rule $\ell_2 \to r_2$ is a rewrite rule that is obtained by applying a substitution to $\ell_2 \to r_2$, thereby instantiating variables in $\ell_2$ and $r_2$.